# Pi Zero as I2C slave

Tags: i2c, pi-zero

I'm trying to set up a Pi Zero as I2C slave via the pigpio library. While receiving data seems to work great, sending data is a problem.

When the host asks for data for a given register, the request goes in to the RX FIFO and sometime later, I get notified. Buy this time, the I2C transaction has taken place and whatever was in the I2C controllers buffer is sent. This occurs even if the TX Fifo is empty. So, the host has no idea if the data it got back was stale or it was in response to what it asked for.

Has anyone found a way around this? Is there a way to force it to NACK if the TX buffer if the TX buffer is empty?  I played with disabling the transmitter until it the data was in the TX FIFO but it seems like the pigpio library seems to want to keep the transmitter enabled.

The only way I can come up with is some sort of signally series of bytes. While it may work, it seems like a lot of hassle to get a simple message back from the slave.